# Потеря знаков при конвертации строки в double

Tags: c#

Есть возможно сделать как-то чтобы не терялись знаки при конвертации строки в double при следующих ситуациях?

```
string number = "12.400";
double result;

var flag = Double.TryParse(number, NumberStyles.Float,
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out result);
```

Результат будет 12.4, а нужно 12.400. Заранее сколько знаков хранить я не знаю. Стандартное готовое решение есть этому или надо парсить строку и получать сколько знаков после разделителя, а потом это использовать в формате?

Comment: для числа с плавающей точкой 12.400000000 и 12.4 - это одно и то же. Если у вам при выводе в консоль/куда ещё пропадают нули, значит вы неверно форматируете вывод числа, но тот код, что вы показали, не имеет к форматированию числа при выводе никакого отношения

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что надо хранить столько знаков, сколько ввёл пользователь? Если да, то лучше хранить исходную строку, и переводить её в число только для внутренних расчётов.

Comment: Проблема не в вводе, т. к. 12.400 и 12.4 — это в точности одно и то же число. Вам нужно поменять формат вывода, чтобы добавлялись незначащие нули.

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal result;
Decimal.TryParse (...);
```

//Все знаки на месте

Comment: Вопрос всё-таки о `double`. Для полноценного ответа хорошо бы объяснить, разницу между double и decimal, и почему в данном случае знаки сохраняются. Ну и о недостатках decimal.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Проблема в том, что с `double` десятичные знаки не имеют смысла. Например, число 12.4 вовсе нельзя точно представить в виде `double`.

Answer (score -1):

Вещественные числа хранятся в памяти в виде: знак (+/-), экспонента (степень показателя системы счисления, чаще всего 2), мантисса (набор битов, которые кодируют мантиссу числа).

В этом смысле числа 12.4 и 12.400 эквивалентны, так как будут храниться в памяти одинаково. Если нужно, храните отдельно количество знаков после запятой. Можете это количество вычислять исходя из строки:

```
string number = "12.400";
int digitCount = number.Split('.')[1].Length;
```

А потом форматировать соответствующим образом:

```
double result;
var flag = Double.TryParse(number, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, out result);
string numberFormated = String.Format("{0:0.".PadRight(digitCount, "0") + "}", result);
```

Comment: Цикл можно заменить вызовом метода [PadRight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/36f2hz3a(v=vs.110).aspx). А проще всего применить один из стандартных [форматов](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), например, `F3`.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, окей, спасибо, что исправили.

Comment: Да, безусловно я понимаю что они эквивалентны, но в силу особых причин клиент хотел чтобы на наших графиках не терялось количество нулей. Скорее всего действительно придется парсить строку получая количество знаков, так как данные могут дать с разным значением и нигде это не регулируется и потом форматировать отображая нужное количество нулей. Думал просто это можно сделать как-то стандартно. Спасибо